# Relationship "Apartment" does not exist EFCORE postgre sql

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I have an asp.net core application with a class called apartment
I defined the relationship between Apartment and Project in the following line.

```
    [ForeignKey("IdProject")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public int IdProject { get; set; }
```

However when I try to get all apartments using this block of code :

```
  var Apartments = _ApartmentRepository.GetAll();
```

I get this error in my output window :

> relation "Apartment" does not exist
>   I didn't find anything helpful researching,

Comment: Have you created your database? You can either use migrations, or the more simple EnsureCreated at program startup during development. Take a look at [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/)